# Sentence alignment for MT in google AutoML

Tags: google-cloud-automl

Does Google AutoML come with a sentence alignment tool?

I have lots of documents in English and Italian which are manually translated "almost" sentence by sentence so it should be easy to detect translated sentences automatically. Documents are grammatically well written relatively short: 5-10 sentences.

Is such tool on the roadmap and what would be a good tool/approach to use until it's included in the AutoML cloud service?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Not by google, I ended up using hunalign (https://github.com/danielvarga/hunalign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bunch of options online to do this:

https://github.com/rsennrich/Bleualign

https://github.com/machinalis/yalign

https://github.com/danielvarga/hunalign

https://github.com/rali-udem/yasa

https://github.com/cocoxu/Shakespeare

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52608

http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~wjb31/distrib/mttkv1/

http://champollion.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I tried bleualign and found it unusable - gave it a toy example of 4-5 sentences and the alignment was messed up. I ended up using hunalign with some custom thresholds based on my data.